# how to validate only user text box

Tags: .net, asp.net, validation, requiredfieldvalidator

I am taking login control in simple format(means with out convert to template) and I placed one link button(forgot password) out side of login control

my issue is when user click on forgot password with out entering username then it displays

'*' beside of user textbox inside login control (it validate only user textbox, no need to validate password textbox)

Answer (score 2):

use validation group

```
ValidationGroup="groupName"
```

like

```
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvName" runat="server" ValidationGroup="gName" ControlToValidate="txtName" ErrorMessage="msg" SetFocusOnError="True"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

<asp:LinkButton ID="lbtn" ValidationGroup="gName" runat="server" >Login</asp:LinkButton>&nbsp;&nbsp;
```